# On the existence of the Moore-Penrose inverse

Tags: hilbert-spaces, pseudoinverse

The following was written in a paper, but I couldn't find out why. Does anyone have any idea on how to prove this claim?

> It is well known that $A^{\dagger}$ exists for a given $A \in B(H, K)$ if and only if $R(A)$ is closed

Where $H$ and $K$  are Hilbert spaces, $B(H,K)$ is space of all bounded linear operators from $H$ to $K$, $A^{\dagger}$ is Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$ and $R(A)$ is range of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V:=\ker(A)^\perp$, which is a Hilbert subspace of $K$, denote with $p$ the orthogonal projection $K\to V$ and $i$ the inclusion $V\to K$. Then if $R(A)$ is closed you get that

$$A\lvert_V:V\to R(A)$$
is a bijective continuous linear map between Banach spaces, hence invertible. In particular $A^*(R(A))=\ker(A)^\perp=V$ is closed, and then
$$R(A^*A)=A^*(R(A))=V$$
is closed. By the same steps as before this makes $(A^*A)\lvert_{V}:V\to V$
into an invertible operator. Let $(A^*A)^+:= i\cdot((A^*A)\lvert_V)^{-1}\cdot p$, which is a linear operator $K\to K$.

Now define
$$A^\dagger = (A^*A)^+A^*$$
which you can check fulfills the properties of being the pseudo-inverse.

For the other direction note that from $AA^\dagger A= A$ you get that $AA^\dagger(K)=R(A)$. But $(AA^\dagger)^2=AA^\dagger$ and $(AA^\dagger)^*=AA^\dagger$ you find that $AA^\dagger$ is an orthogonal projection and so must have closed range. Hence $R(A)$ is closed.